# Why are my server’s emails are going to others’ “unwanted” or “junk” folders?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

My email accounts are working properly and my (shared) server IP doesn’t seem to be blacklisted. When sending emails, I do not get any bounce messages. The emails I send all look fine and their content is plain text. They don’t contain any trigger words such as “test.”

Though, it seems like Google Gmail servers have been flagging my emails as “Junk” for a very long time but other providers, such as Yahoo Mail, don’t. Creating more email accounts didn’t help. I have also used email accounts that belonged to different domains.

How can avoid Gmail servers from flagging my emails as “unwanted?”